# Deleting lines automatically which are not connected in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line

[image]

I have a shapefile consisting of polylines. I have managed to explode these polylines (break at there vertices). There are a bunch of lines all over the shapefile which are not connected (shown in the red boxes).

Is there a way to delete them automatically. What I mean is **not** selecting them individually because its difficult to manually locate each and every line which isn't connected.

Comment: Did you use the tool: Vector> Sample> Spatial Sampling - Tick Include input layer objects related to selected objects?

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use GRASS, you can do this with the `v.clean` module, choosing the `rmdangle` tool, and a suitable threshold.

```
# STart GRASS using your polyline shapefile (to determine the coordinate system for a new location)
grass -c polyline.shp YourPathToGISDBASE/YourLocation/YourMapset
# Import the shapefile
v.import polyline.shp output=polylines
# And do the remove dangles operation
v.clean polylines tool=rmdangle thresh=xxxx output=polylines2
```

The xxxx value is some length that makes sense in your situation: larger than the length of the dangles. You might want to run several times, each time with a slightly larger threshold value, until you find what works.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the ["Extract by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) tool with an expression that contains the [`overlay_touches()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-touches) function:

```
overlay_touches(@layer)
```

*Before:*
[image: input]

*After:*
[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have a large road network that you are interested in and would like to discard the 'small networks' that consist of fewer number of links (like the one on the top right).

I would approach the problem like this:

1. merge all the polylines that touch/intersect (let's say this wields merged_network) - see [Join / merge lines that touch and intersect in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198317/join-merge-lines-that-touch-and-intersect-in-qgis)
2. from merged_network I would select the 'large' road network that I am interested in (merged_network_clear)
3. using merged_network_clear I would select by location all the original polylines that intersect/touch it

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method is to use the ["Service area"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#service-area-from-layer) tools in QGIS.

You can use this tool with a really long distance to find what is connected to the main network

Then use that to select the lines from the original layer and export them out

[image: ScreenshotV2]