# Joining all hydrographic vectors touching each other (inside same feature) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hydrography

I have a complex hydrographic layer where all the hydrographic lines are separate even if it's from the same river.

How do I select all the vectors who are touching themselves without select vector from another river using automation ?

I'm on Qgis.

Comment: How does your attribute table look like? Are all features, which belong to the same river, marked accordingly, e.g. by an ID or the rivers name?

Comment: Please provide more detail about the data structure/attribute

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198317/join-merge-lines-that-touch-and-intersect-in-qgis

Please take a look at this. If your vectors are lines, this might help you in merging and then grouping by the "river" attribute.

Comment: All the ID are differents.
Actually, my problem is exactly the same as the raaj's link. 
Problem is, the script from your link is not working on QGIS3 ...

Comment: try `dissolve` followed by `multipart to singleparts`

Comment: Thank you for your help guys :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is not in attribute table anything that identifies the rivers by name or something. So keeping information from the table does not seem an issue either. Otherwise, maybe a spatial join could be tried to join that information afterwards.

This code with `python`, `geopandas` and `shapely`'s [ops.linemerge](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.linemerge) should do the trick.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import linemerge

def merge_lines():
    lines_gdf = gpd.read_file("you_file.geojson") # or .shp or wathever
    geometries = list(lines_gdf.geometry)
    merged_lines = linemerge(geometries)
    lines_dict = {}
    for i, line in enumerate(merged_lines):
        lines_dict[i] = gpd.GeoSeries({
            'id': i,
            'geometry': line
        })

    new_lines_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(lines_dict)
    new_lines_gdf.to_file("your_new_file.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")
```

Comment: Okay, you have to tell me where to write this code, because I'm a total newbie in QGIS :D

Comment: That's with python as stand alone, outside of QGIS. For automation tends to be faster and easier.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try this soon ;)
Thank you !