# QGIS merge line within 1 long line

Tags: qgis, line, polyline-creation

I have a long line, which is separated by nodes. How could I merge them to make just one very long line?

[image]

This is a similar query here:

[Join / merge lines that touch and intersect in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198317/join-merge-lines-that-touch-and-intersect-in-qgis)

But is it possible to do it without coding?

Comment: A dissolve on the selected inputs didn't work?

Comment: this is also a handy plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/joinmultiplelines/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proceed as follows:

1. Select all, <kbd>[merge selected features](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#merge-selected-features)</kbd><sup>1</sup>
2. <kbd>[Multpart to single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts)</kbd>

<sup>1</sup> Must be a multipart layer; copy/paste the line to a new multipart layer if that is not the case.